# Group By and Sum Based on Two Fields in Dataframe with MultiIndex

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, header, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to do a GroupBy and Sum, but it's a little tricky because I think I need to do this based on two Headers in my data frame.  I need two headers in a specific data frame, so I'm setting that accordingly.

```
df = pd.read_csv(f, delimiter='\t', skiprows=0, header=[0,1])
```

When I list all the fields in my data frame, I see this.

```
my_list = list(df_append)
my_list
```

Then ...

```
    [('IDRSSD', 'Unnamed: 0_level_1'),
     ('RCFD3531', 'TRDG ASSETS-US TREAS SECS IN DOM OFF'),
     ('RCFD3532', 'TRDG ASSETS-US GOV AGC CORP OBLGS'),
     ('RCFD3533', 'TRDG ASSETS-SECS ISSD BY ST  POL SUB'),
     ('RCFD3541', 'TRDG ASSETS-OTHER IN DOMESTIC OFFCS'),
     ('RCFD3543', 'TRDG ASSETS-REVALUTN GAINS'),
     ('RCFD3545', 'TOTAL TRADING ASSETS'),
    ..., etc.
     ('RCONK210', 'TRDG ASSETS OTHR CNSMR LN TO INDV HH'),
     ('RCONK211', 'UNPD PRIN BAL LN MSD FV OTHR CNSMR L'),
     ('Unnamed: 139_level_0', 'Unnamed: 139_level_1'),
     ('file', ''),
     ('schedule_code', ''),
     ('year', ''),
     ('qyear', '')]
```

My problem is with this thing: `('IDRSSD', 'Unnamed: 0_level_1')`.

For instance, if I do this:

```
df_append.columns.values[:1] = [['IDRSSD','IDRSSD']]
```

Then, I re-list, I get this.

```
[['IDRSSD', 'IDRSSD'],
 ('RCFD3531', 'TRDG ASSETS-US TREAS SECS IN DOM OFF'),
 ('RCFD3532', 'TRDG ASSETS-US GOV AGC CORP OBLGS'),
 ('RCFD3533', 'TRDG ASSETS-SECS ISSD BY ST  POL SUB'),
..., etc.
 ('RCONK210', 'TRDG ASSETS OTHR CNSMR LN TO INDV HH'),
 ('RCONK211', 'UNPD PRIN BAL LN MSD FV OTHR CNSMR L'),
 ('Unnamed: 139_level_0', 'Unnamed: 139_level_1'),
 ('file', ''),
 ('schedule_code', ''),
 ('year', ''),
 ('qyear', '')]
```

So, things look ok at this point, but when I run this:

```
grouped_and_summed = df_append.groupby(['IDRSSD','qyear']).sum()
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-74-489d4047576f>", line 1, in <module>
    grouped_and_summed = df_append.groupby(['IDRSSD','qyear']).sum()

  File "C:\Users\ryans\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 6521, in groupby
    dropna=dropna,

  File "C:\Users\ryans\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 533, in __init__
    dropna=self.dropna,

  File "C:\Users\ryans\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\grouper.py", line 809, in get_grouper
    if not isinstance(gpr, Grouping)

  File "C:\Users\ryans\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\grouper.py", line 517, in __init__
    raise ValueError(f"Grouper for '{t}' not 1-dimensional")

ValueError: Grouper for 'IDRSSD' not 1-dimensional
```

I tried to name it, but I couldn't figure out how to do it.  Somehow...I want to be able to Group By and Sum, like this:

`grouped_and_summed = df_append.groupby(['IDRSSD','qyear']).sum()`

Comment: what is ```df_append```?

Comment: I have appended several CSV files into one data frame, named df_append.  The double-header is throwing me off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some extensive research, I found out that this issue has to do with the mulit-column index!  Any type of grouping on a data frame with a mulit-column index generates this error.

This is the solution:

```
df_append.columns = df_append.columns.get_level_values(0)
```

Then, you can do the Group By and Sum, normally:

```
grouped_and_summed = df_append.groupby(['IDRSSD','qyear']).sum()
```